# Etymology of "informal British" word "bent" (meaning: dishonest, corrupt)

Tags: etymology

I have been seeing some of my British friends using the word **"bent"** to mean *dishonest, cheater, immoral* etc. "Bent" as adjective is defined in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bent) as *British informal Dishonest; corrupt*.

I wonder where it got this sense. I searched different etymology dictionaries such as [Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bent), [Online Etymology Dictionary (Etymonline)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/bent), [Etymology Online](http://www.etymology-online.com/bent), [Etymology Geek](https://etymologeek.com/eng/bent/38017273) but none of them says anything about this sense of "bent".

Etymonline has a note about the adjective "bent" but it is about the shape (*curved*). I have no access to [Green Dictionary of slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/). Can someone tell me where "bent" acquired this sense?

Comment: I imagine it is influenced by  "crook" and "crooked", these are used to mean "criminal" and also mean "bent".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It apparently derives from the expression:

***[on the bend](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/ewsmieq#tprw4ta) (adj.)***

1. crooked, criminal, underhand [predates bent adj. (3) but presumably its derivation].

> - 1863    [UK]    J.C. Jeaffreson Live it Down II 152: *I never have paid anything yet on the square, and I never will. When I die, I’ll order my executor to buy my coffin off the square. He shall get it on the bend somehow or other [F&H].*

***[Bent](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/xvkcw6i#sn3)*** :

3. criminal; corrupt; thus on the bend under bend n.1 ; thus bent copper, bent screw, corrupt police officer, prison-warder.

> - 1914    [US]    Jackson & Hellyer Vocab. Criminal Sl. 17: *bent [...] crooked; larcenous. Example: His kisser shows that he’s bent.*
>   Blockquote
> - 1931    [US]    Irwin Amer. Tramp and Und. Sl. 26: *Bent.—Crooked ; criminal ; outside the law. Directly the opposite of ‘straight,’ and applied to individuals, enterprises or goods.*

(GDoS)

But probably as a synonym of [crooked](https://www.etymonline.com/word/crooked) whose figurative sense of dishonest dates back to the 13th century.

> early 13c., "bent, curved, in a bent shape,". In the figurative sense of "dishonest, false, treacherous, not straight in conduct" is from c. 1200.

Comment: Oh... thanks! I knew it would be present in GDoS but my browser just wouldn't let me open it

Comment: It's just the opposite of 'straight', in the sense of 'honest' (not 'heterosexual').

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - if you have a different answer and source just post it.